# Calling webservice in parallel using aysnc

Tags: c#, winforms, asynchronous, soap-client

I'm trying to write a winforms app that retrieves a list of ids from a SOAP web service, then goes through that list, calling another web service to get individual details. To speed things up I'm doing these requests in parallel, in batches of 15.

When the web service calls all return OK, my application works great. However in my testing, if 2 or more requests timeout (I'm monitoring the requests using Fiddler and see I'm getting a 408), then it appears that the process hangs and I never get the completion message my programs should be displaying.

What I'd like to do if possible is retry these requests, or just tell the user to press the button again because an error occurred.

When adding the service reference, I made sure the generate task-based operations option was used.

Here is the code I've got so far (with some details renamed as not to give away the company I'm interfacing with):

```
 private async void btnDownload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                Stopwatch watch = new Stopwatch();
                watch.Start();

                IProgress<string> progress = new Progress<string>(s =>
                {
                    lbinfo.Items.Insert(0, s);
                });

                await GetData(progress);

                watch.Stop();

                progress.Report("Took " + (watch.ElapsedMilliseconds / 1000f) + " seconds. All done.");
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Main Click: "+ex.ToString());
            }
        }

 private async Task GetData(IProgress<string> progress)
        {
            try
            {
                DownloadSoapClient client = new DownloadSoapClient();
                client.Open();

                progress.Report("Getting master list.");
                List<int> uniqueIds = await GetMasterList(client); //this always seems to work

                progress.Report("Downloaded master list. Found "+uniqueIds.Count +" unique ids.");

                var detailedData = await GetIdDataRaw(uniqueIds, client,progress);

                client.Close();

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                progress.Report("GetData: "+ex);
            }
        }

       private async Task<List<DownloadResponse>> GetIdDataRaw(List<int> ids, DownloadSoapClient client, IProgress<string> progress)
        {
            using (var throttler = new SemaphoreSlim(15))
            {
                var allTasks = ids.Select(async x =>
                    {
                        await throttler.WaitAsync();

                        try
                        {
                            progress.Report(x.ToString());
                            return await client.DownloadAsync(username, password, x);

                        }
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {
                            progress.Report("Error getting id:" + x + " " + ex.Message);
                            return null;
                        }
                        finally
                        {
                            throttler.Release();
                        }
                    });

                return (await Task.WhenAll(allTasks)).ToList();
            }
        }
```

Typically the master list is around 1000 entries, and when only 1 times out, as expected I get a message saying there was an error getting id xxxx, and then "Took xx seconds. All done.".

So far I've tried a few other things, such as creating a client for each request, and refactoring to use Task.WhenAny in a while loop, but these exhibit the same behaviour when 2 or more requests fail.

Comment: The task returned from `Task.WhenAll` will not complete until all of its tasks have completed. This is true regardless of errors. Are you sure you're not seeing some situation where the server is misbehaving?

Comment: As far as I can tell from looking at the responses in Fiddler, all of the requests I'm making are completing, either with a 200, or 408.

Comment: What is the default timeout when calling the method `client.DownloadAsync`?

Comment: I think it's 60 seconds. At least that is what client.InnerChannel.OperationTimeout is when I inspect it.

Comment: Can you specify from your logs and progress bar at what stage your applications hangs?

Comment: Well, it doesn't hang per se, its that the "Took xx seconds. All done." is not shown. So the last thing shown in the listbox that the progress function reports to is an id, but I guess that may or not be the one that errors because things are happening in parallel.